# Dynamically populating meta information using server component in NextJS13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to update a server component to use the NextJS server component [metadata object][1] and populate it with the returned object from a server call I make for content to populate the component. In the examples it appears that this meta information population needs to happen in a separate function call, but I'm hoping to avoid making two calls to the same endpoint unnecessarily. Am I misinterpreting how I can dynamically insert the meta information for this server component?

Here is my current structure:

```
import React from 'react';
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';

import { getSinglePost } from '@/libs/ghost';

type Props = {
  params: { title: string, description: string };
};

export async function Post({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
  console.log(params.slug);
  const posts = await getSinglePost(params.slug);

  export const metadata = async ({ params }: Props): Metadata => {
    return {
        title: posts?.title,
        description: posts?.excerpt
    }
    }
  }

  if (posts) {
    const options = {
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
      year: 'numeric',
    }; 

    posts.dateFormatted = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(
      new Date(posts.published_at)
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className='container mx-auto'>
      <div className='flex flex-col md:px-10 py-5 md:py-10'>
        <div className='flex flex-col lg:px-44' id='content-header'>
          <div className='py-5'>
            <Link href={`/tag/${posts?.primary_tag?.name?.toLowerCase()}`}>
              <h3 className='text-md md:text-2xl text-gold-500 hover:text-gold-700'>
                {posts?.primary_tag?.name}
              </h3>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div id='header-title'>
            <h1 className='text-3xl md:text-5xl'>{posts?.title}</h1>
            <h3 className='py-6 font-bold'>
              {posts?.dateFormatted} <span class='bull px-3'>&bull;</span>{' '}
              Reading Time: {posts?.reading_time} Minutes
            </h3>
            <h2 className='py-3 italic text-md md:text-xl' id='content-footer'>
              {posts?.excerpt}
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div className='md:mx-auto overflow-hidden  md:h-full relative md:order-last'>
            <Image
              src={posts?.feature_image}
              width={600}
              height={400}
              className='max-md:h-32 object-cover'
              alt='Test'
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className='prose dark:prose-invert lg:px-44 pt-10 max-w-none prose-p:text-lg prose-blockquote:text-lg tracking-wide leading-7'
          id='content-body'
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: posts?.html }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}




  [1]: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#metadata-fields
```